# Как сделать неактивными кнопки и их стиль в Kotlin Anko

Tags: android, kotlin

Как программно сделать неактивной кнопку в Kotlin с разметкой Anko? Не могу найти нужный метод. UI вынесен отдельный класс.

```
class FragmentButtonsUi : AnkoComponent<FragmentButtons> {

var buttonAccept : Button? = null
var buttonReject : Button? = null

override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<FragmentButtons>): View = with(ui) {
    constraintLayout {
        id = R.id.constraintButton
        lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

        buttonAccept = button("Accept") {
            id = R.id.buttonAccept

            onClick {
                ui.owner.buttonAcceptOnClick()
            }

        }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent) {
            topToTop = R.id.constraintButton
            leftToLeft = R.id.constraintButton
        }

        buttonReject = button("Reject") {
            id = R.id.buttonReject

            onClick {
                ui.owner.buttonRejectOnClick()
            }

        }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent) {
            topToTop = R.id.constraintButton
            rightToRight = R.id.constraintButton
        }

    }
}
```

Дальше из класса, в котором я подтягиваю эту разметку хочу обратиться к кнопками, чтобы сделать их неактивными, но не пойму как..
Например

```
val fragmentButtonsUi = FragmentButtonsUi()
fragmentButtonsUi.buttonAccept.??????
```

Нет метода, как например setEnabled в Java... Или просто это пока не реализованно в этой библиотеке?

EDIT:
Как поменять цвет кнопки? меняю через

```
fragmentButtonsUi.buttonAccept?.backgroundColor = Color.GREEN
```

При этом кнопка меняет форму - острые углы. Как применить цвет, чтобы форма самой кнопки осталась дефолтной?

Comment: Про цвет, его надо не менять напрямую, а тинтить кнопку: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884131/5479247

Comment: Спасибо! Я нашел)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел....

`fragmentButtonsUi.buttonAccept?.isClickable = false
fragmentButtonsUi.buttonReject?.background?.setTint(Color.RED)`

Answer (score 2):

`Anko` тут совсем не при чем. Все дело в том как Kotlin интерпретирует геттеры и сеттеры.
В документации все описано:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Причем Java-овский синтаксис никто не отменял. Пишите себе на здоровье

```
fragmentButtonsUi.buttonAccept?.setEnabled(false)
```

Но по Kotlin-овски будет так

```
fragmentButtonsUi.buttonAccept?.isEnabled = false
```

Так что изучайте язык, на котором пишете и все будет проще.